# Accessing ViewBag in Controller that's set in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I understand I can do this using ModelBinding, but I'd like to know if I can use the `ViewBag`

I set the `ViewBag` property in the View

```
@{
ViewBag.WasPriorityCustomer = Model.PriorityCustomer == true;
}
```

A user who is not a priority customer can be changed to one, but i need to know if they were a priority customer to begin with.

In the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyModel model)
{
  if (ViewBag.WasPriorityCustomer == false && model.PriorityCustomer == true)
  {
    //Thank you for becoming a priority customer
  }
}
```

Unfortunately `ViewBag.WasPriorityCustomer` is always null

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve... `ViewBag` only goes from Controller to View and not the other way around. You need to post `WasPriorityCustomer` together with your form to your controller.

Answer (score 3):

You just try to do things in the wrong way :

You can set a `ViewBag`'s value in an action, and use it's value in the generated view.

But to get a value from a view in the `POST` action, you should use an hidden input.

something like that in the view (untested) :

```
@ {bool wasPriorityCustomer = Model.PriorityCustomer;}

@Html.Hidden("wasPriorityCustomer", wasPriorityCustomer)
```

and Action becomes

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyModel model, bool wasPriorityCustomer)
```

or you could change your ViewModel to include the "hidden" value.

and use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.WasPriorityCustomer)`

Comment: IF i use a hidden input, then i need to update the View model which I don't want to do if not absolutely ncessary

Comment: @DotnetDude well, I completed answer and gave an alternative

Comment: @DotnetDude. Hidden field is appropriate here. Bite the bullet and include WaPriorityCustomer either in your model or as a parameter on your action. Please don't use session for this.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus. +1 for hidden field. -1 for session suggestion. Result 0. :)

Comment: @flem thx for the +1, nevermind the -1 ;) Why "absolutely" no session here ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus. It's an inappropriate use of sessionstate. Plus there are further implications of using session state depending on the hosting architecture. Hidden field is the right answer, you should stick with that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code if you want to store some value in viewBag and want to use in this ViewBag value in View.

In Model Action

```
ViewBag.Test = ("NewTest");
```

in View you can write

```
@ViewBag.ProcedureTypeId
```

This way you can have `ViewBag` value in `Viewpage`